# Ginzburg-Landau and Coherence Length

Tags: superconductivity, superfluidity

Consider the Ginzburg-Landau functional for a complex function $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{C}$, i.e.,
$$
F[\psi]=\int \frac{1}{2M}|(-i\hbar\nabla -eA)\psi|^2+r|\psi|^2+\frac{u}{2}|\psi|^4 + \frac{B^2}{2\mu}
$$
Textbooks usually claim that the amplitude of $\psi$ varies very little on length scales larger than the coherence $\xi$, which is defined as
$$
\xi^2 = \frac{\hbar^2}{2M |r|}
$$
Now I understand that $\xi$ is a good guess for the *characteristic* length scale of the system, in the sense that it has the correct units, and that if $r>0$ and we were to ignore higher order terms (i.e., set $u=0$) and restrict ourselves to the zero magnetic field case $A=0$, then the functional would correspond to a free Hamiltonian with Green functions decaying as $e^{-|x-y|/\xi}$ and thus you *maybe could* say that the amplitudes possibly vary only on length scales $\le \xi$ (though the details of such claim eludes me, i.e., I don't know how to prove that $\langle [|\psi(x)|-|\psi(y)|]^2\rangle \to 0$ as $|x-y|\to \infty$).

However, even accepting these arguments, how would one justify that $|\psi|$ does not vary on legnth scales larger than $\xi$ in the superconducting state $r<0$?